# How to use photo from photo library ios every time the apps loads?

Tags: ios, swift4

im trying to do the follow : user is picking image from photo lib as profile pic -> from now on this image will use as profile pic even if the app closed .

im using this code :

```
        if let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.referenceURL] as? NSURL { 
          // how can i get the pic url that i can use it when the app is starting ? 
        }
```

this is the way i loading photos right now : ( the path is taken from assets )

`var img = UIImage(named:getAvatarPath());`

btw im using swift 4 .

thanks .

Comment: can you share the code of `getAvatarPath()` method?

Comment: It returns the name of the picture from asset store .

Comment: You can save the image name or URL in `UserDefaults` and fetch it from there when user opens the app

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR thanks! i think ill save the url . how do i load it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the image name or URL to `UserDefaults`.
Here is a code snippet to save URL string to `UserDefaults`.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(avatarUrl, forKey: "userAvatar")
```

And retrieve the URL when displaying the image.
Something like this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userAvatar") as? String
```

You can also create a `property` in a `class` or `struct` by combining the above approaches to save/retrieve a property to/from `UserDefaults`.
for example:

```
var userAvatar = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userAvatar") as? String {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(avatarUrl, forKey: "userAvatar")
    }
}
```

Now you can use this `property` to save or load the image URL string using `UserDefaults`.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks! but how do i load the ui image with the saved url ?

Comment: Thats a separate question. But there are various ways to load image from a `URL`. I think this thread might be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680